# Spring API @RequestParam Input conversion

Tags: spring, string, api, enums, uuid

I am creating a method for an API. In this method i have some parameters that are optional. those are filters for searching an event. when i try to run it and type the following url:

> http://localhost:8181/api/events?id=gRDHzDh9TdiLDAZgrZc2wg==

i get this error message:

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.UUID'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: gRDHzDh9TdiLDAZgrZc2wg==

So i understand that i insert a String in my url and expect a UUID in code, but how do i convert this? Below here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping(
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity getEvents(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) UUID eventId,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "playtype", required = false) PlayType playType,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "skilllevel", required = false) SkillLevel skillLevel,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "sporttype", required = false) SportType sportType,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "long", required = false) String _long,
                                    @RequestParam(value = "lat", required = false) String lat) {
        try {
            List<Event> events = eventService.getEvents(eventId, title, playType, skillLevel, sportType, _long, lat);
            if (events.size() == 0) {
                return new ResponseEntity("No events found", HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity(events, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

So here are my 2 questions:

1. How do i convert the string to a valid UUID input in the RequestParam?
2. How do i convert the string to a valid enum in the RequestParam? (because with the enums i have the same error)

**EDIT**

my code is now like this:

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
)
public ResponseEntity getEvents(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String eventId,
                                @RequestParam(value = "title", required = false) String title,
                                @RequestParam(value = "playtype", required = false) String playType,
                                @RequestParam(value = "skilllevel", required = false) String skillLevel,
                                @RequestParam(value = "sporttype", required = false) String sportType,
                                @RequestParam(value = "long", required = false) String _long,
                                @RequestParam(value = "lat", required = false) String lat) {
    UUID id = null;
    PlayType playType1 = null;
    SkillLevel skillLevel1 = null;
    SportType sportType1 = null;
    try {
        if (eventId != null){
            id = UUID.fromString(eventId);
        }
        if (playType != null){
            playType1 = PlayType.valueOf(playType);
        }
        if (skillLevel != null){
            skillLevel1 = SkillLevel.valueOf(skillLevel);
        }
        if (sportType != null){
            sportType1 = SportType.valueOf(sportType);
        }
        List<Event> events = eventService.getEvents(id, title, playType1, skillLevel1, sportType1, _long, lat);
        if (events.size() == 0) {
            return new ResponseEntity("No events found", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(events, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        return new ResponseEntity(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

but i still get an error:

> Invalid UUID string: gRDHzDh9TdiLDAZgrZc2wg==

Comment: Are you _actually_ expecting a valid java UUID as that ID is not one.

Comment: `@RequestParam` will automatically do the conversion (however your supplied value isn't remotely a valid UUID). NO need to do all the manual conversion as Spring is perfectly capable of doing that for you. Basically what you are supplying aren't valid values for the types you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. How do I convert the string to a valid UUID input?

> You need to use `UUID.fromString()` API, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#fromString(java.lang.String))

2. How do i convert the string to a valid enum?

> You need to use `Enum.valueOf()` API, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name())

Comment: But i can't put that behind the @RequestParam. because i get the error message even before it enters the method

Comment: you can make your `@RequestParams` Strings and convert them to appropriate type in the method.

Comment: That's because you're passing the invalid UUID on the `@RequestParam`, you can verify the valid UUID's here http://guid.us/Test/GUID